# querySelector not working with class but work with id

Tags: javascript

I've the below `html` block:

```
    <a class="item">
      <i class="sign out icon" id="out1"></i>
      <span class="text out" id="out2">Sign out</span>
    </a>
```

I need to trigger an action if any of the elements inside the `a` is clicked, the below code is working fine when I use the items `id`:

```
document.querySelector("#out1, #out2").onclick = function(e) {}
```

But the below is not working when I'm trying the items `class`:

```
document.querySelector(".sign .out .icon, .text .out").onclick = function(e) {}
```

I tried to make it simple by the below, but it did not work as well:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".out").onclick = function(e) {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.querySelector` works like `css` selectors, `document.querySelector('.sign .out .icon')` will look for an element with the class `icon` inside an element `.out` inside `.sign` , it should work fine if you remove the spaces :

```
document.querySelector(".sign.out.icon, .text.out").onclick = function(e) {}
```

keep in mind that `querySelector` will return the first match, so a comma in the selectors string isn't that much useful , [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) :

> The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within
>   the document that matches the specified selector, or group of
>   selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a node list, you have to loop through it amd handle the `onclick` or access the first element with `[0]` :

```
document.querySelectorAll(".out")[0].onclick = function(e) {}
```

```js
const a = document.querySelector(".sign .out .icon, .text .out");
const b = document.querySelector(".sign.out.icon, .text.out");

console.log({a, b});

const c = document.querySelectorAll(".out");

console.log(c[0]);
```

```html
<a class="item">
  <i class="sign out icon" id="out1"></i>
  <span class="text out" id="out2">Sign out</span>
</a>
```

To add listner for `ALL`, then `forEach` can be used as below:

```
var out = document.querySelectorAll(".out");

out.forEach((e) => {
  e.onclick = function(e) {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/logout')
      .then(window.location.reload(true));
  };
});
```

Comment: A comma in selectors for `querySelector` doesn't make sense. Can see in log it only finds the `<i>`